# cant add solution from vs.net 2010 to subversion repository?

Tags: visual-studio, svn

I created a subversion repository on my server . Now I am trying to add a vs.net 2010 solution + AnkhSVN support from another machine in the network . I comes up with an error 'plse select a location in the repository to add to' ?
[image]

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Your have shown a dialog but not explained the problem. Have you tried clicking the OK button? It is asking you for a folder to add your code to in the repository.

Comment: Also ... I recommend clicking the 'Add trunk folder' option.